# How to map SQL Server tables to DataTables correctly?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datatable, dbnull

I wrote a method which copies a table from SQL Server to a .NET-DataTable:

```
public static DataTable SQLtoDataTable(string _connectionString, string _tableName)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string queryString = "SELECT * FROM " + _tableName;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand queryCMD = new SqlCommand(queryString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(queryCMD))
            {
                queryCMD.Connection = connection;
                connection.Open();
                da.Fill(dt);
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
   }

   return dt;
}
```

Unfortunately this method does not seem to work 100% correctly. While columns and row data are transferred 1:1, it seems like the `AllowDBNULL` value is set to `true` for every single column no matter if it is set to `true` or `false` in the database. Do I miss something or is there a better way to insert this kind of information into a `DataTable`?

Comment: "How to map SQL-tables to DataTables correctly?" - correct is subjective; personally, I'm of the opinion that the "correct" mapping to `DataTable` is "as rarely as possible, when all other possible models have been eliminated"... is there any reason you can't represent this in a proper object model?

Comment: @MarcGravell Well by correctly I mean fetching as much correct data from SQL to DataTable as possible. What exactly do you mean by representing this in a proper object model, LINQ?

Comment: For example, if you need to model customers and orders, a `class Customer {...}` and `class Order {...}`. `DataTable` is not the way to go for data access / storage, IMO.

Comment: @MarcGravell Because my methods are supposed to be generic. I do not know if my table will be called *Customer* or *Order*.

Comment: `public static List<T> ReadTable<T>(...)`. Table name could be passed in as a string, or could just use the `typeof(T).Name`, or `typeof(T).GetCustomAttribute<TableName>().Name`. Plenty of options there. The only time you **need** to use `DataTable` (or a similar approach) is when writing a tool like SSMS, in which the structure **cannot** be known in advance.

Comment: @MarcGravell This sounds like the thing I was looking for. Could you point me in the right direction or name me some keywords to google for, if I want learn about the things you have described above?

Comment: classes, generics, attributes, micro-orm

Comment: @MarcGravell Either you do not get what I am asking for or I do not get what you are suggesting. Why micro-orm if I could use LINQ? As far as I got it with your suggestion I still would need to implement a class for every new Table I want to read. I want my method to get full data on the fly.

Comment: getting data fully on the fly is an *incredibly* rare requirement, but yes: `DataTable` can be useful there. That mainly applies when writing systems like http://data.stackexchange.com/ which has ad-hoc querying and no in-advance schema (it works against any database). If that is what you are doing: fine. As for LINQ : yes, tools like EF are also options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at using [SqlDataAdapter.FillSchema Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.fillschema(v=vs.110).aspx) with your code.

> Adds a DataTable to a DataSet and configures the schema to match that
>   in the data source.

As an example also have a look at [DbDataAdapter.FillSchema Method (DataSet, SchemaType)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135707(v=vs.110).aspx)

> A FillSchema operation adds a DataTable to the destination DataSet. It
>   then adds columns to the DataColumnCollection of the DataTable, and
>   configures the following DataColumn properties if they exist at the
>   data source:
>
> • AllowDBNull
>
> • AutoIncrement. You must set AutoIncrementStep and AutoIncrementSeed
>   separately.
>
> • MaxLength
>
> • ReadOnly
>
> • Unique
>
> FillSchema also configures the PrimaryKey and Constraints properties
>   according to the following rules:
>
> • If one or more primary key columns are returned by the
>   SelectCommand, they are used as the primary key columns for the
>   DataTable.
>
> • If no primary key columns are returned but unique columns are, the
>   unique columns are used as the primary key if, and only if, all the
>   unique columns are nonnullable. If any of the columns are nullable, a
>   UniqueConstraint is added to the ConstraintCollection, but the
>   PrimaryKey property is not set.
>
> • If both primary key columns and unique columns are returned, the
>   primary key columns are used as the primary key columns for the
>   DataTable.

The example used

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet(dataSetName);

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
        "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName FROM dbo.Customers", connection);

    DataTableMapping mapping = adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Customers");
    mapping.ColumnMappings.Add("CompanyName", "Name");
    mapping.ColumnMappings.Add("ContactName", "Contact");

    connection.Open();

    adapter.FillSchema(dataSet, SchemaType.Mapped);
    adapter.Fill(dataSet);

    return dataSet;
}
```